# The requested URL /application/index.jsf was not found on this server(Apache and Tomcat)

Tags: apache, jsf, tomcat

I am a stackoverflow fan. This website has solved most of technical questions without even asking them but by only reading previous similar questions. Indeed I have searched the web and stackoverflow but I could not find any answer and I could not solve this problem by myself. My only resort is to ask for your help. I have worked on a small JSF 2.0 application and everything is working fine on my local tomcat 6.0.35. I have all the JSF lib on my WEB-INF. I am using mojarra version 2.1.14. The url is accessed like this

on my local

```
  http://localhost/application/page.jsf
```

and this application is deployed to an external hosted tomcat which has apache and Tomcat 6.0.36. The application is deployed under /home/username/public_html. the same url should be accessed by typing

```
http://website.com/application/page.jsf
```

but I am getting the error:

*Not Found*

The requested URL /application/page.jsf was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Additionally, html and JSP pages are working fine. I have a test application which has jsp page and it is loading just fine. xhtml pages on the other hand are not working on this  apache box. For the JSP pages to work I added JSP and servlet support

```
 /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/addservlets2 --domain=domain.com
```

This is the web.xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
     <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
   </context-param>
  </web-app>
```

I strongly believe this web.xml has nothing to do with jsf not working and furthermore these settings are working well on my local. The tomcat log file is showing no error of page not found on the external host.

Here is the faces config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">


 </faces-config>
```

What is happening? Please help me. I am getting desperate. Why JSF request are returning *not found*  on this apache server?

additional the el-impl-2.2.jar and el-api-2.2.jar are in the tomcat libs.
and javax.faces-2.1.14.jar, jstl-api-2.1.jar, jstl-impl-2.1.jar and all the required commons jars are all in the WEB-INF.

Comment: How are you installing this project on the web server? With a WAR file?

Comment: I have deployed the war file under webapps and and when it was unpacked, I copied it to /home/username/public_html/application/. After that I started tomcat. You can then delete war file since webapps here is not the deployment directory.

Comment: The server.xml file has the following important info  

<Host name="domain.com" appBase="/home/username/public_html">
          <Alias>www.website.com</Alias> 
          <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/username/public_html" debug="1"/>
          <Context path="/manager" debug="0" privileged="true"
              docBase="/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/server/webapps/manager">
          </Context>
       </Host>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just fixed this problem. I have spent 6 days doing investigations how to fix this. What a waste of time. Today at work, I talked to my colleague and he suggested I direct my investigations toward apache connector to tomcat since I was claiming that everything is working fine on my local tomcat server.  I made some research and I discovered that I needed to edit cp_jkmount.conf connector. JkMount is used to map a context path to a Tomcat worker. I added the following

```
 <IfModule mod_jk.c>
     JkMount /*.xhtml ajp13
     JkMount /*.jsf ajp13
 </IfModule>
```

at the end of these connectors

```
 /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/username/website.com/cp_jkmount.conf  

 /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/ssl/2/username/website.com/cp_jkmount.conf
```

I hope this will help someone else.